# seleniumで「ファイルを選択」ボタンでローカルからファイルを読み込みたいのですができません。

Tags: python, python3, jupyter-notebook, selenium

こんにちは。
python seleniumで「ファイルを選択」ボタンでローカルからファイルを読み込みたいのですができません。
`input type="file" id="fl" name="fl"`が「ファイルを選択」のHTMLです。
わかる方教えて下さい。
よろしくお願いします。

#### 取得したいHTML

```
<strong>注意事項</strong>
<ul>
<li>各ファイルはモールよりこまめにダウンロードして本システムにアップロードしてください。</li>
<li>アップロードしたタイミングでも在庫の更新対象になります。</li>
<li>在庫数は商品マスタの在庫が正ですのでモール商品CSVファイル内の在庫数は無視します。</li>
</ul>

                            </div>
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">モール商品CSVファイル</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="file" id="fl" name="fl">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>

                            <div class="form-actions">
                                <button type="button submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    モール商品CSVファイルをアップロード<i class="icon-upload-alt"></i>
                                </button>
                                <p id="msg" style="border:none"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="block span12">
                        <p class="block-heading">アップロードメッセージを表示</p>
                        <div class="block-body">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <div class="textarea">
                                        <textarea id="temp" class="span12" rows="10" readonly=""></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="block span12">
                        <p class="block-heading">商品CSVファイル取込予約状況を表示</p>
                        <div class="block-body">
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <div class="textarea">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="status" onclick="status_check()">
                                        取込状況を表示<i class="icon-time"></i>
                                    </button>


                                    <div id="res_result"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
下記に記載
```

#### 該当のソースコードpython

↓以下、色々と試してみましたが駄目でした。

```
●element = driver.find_element_by_name("fl")  #駄目
element.click()

エラー→InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument


●username = driver.find_element_by_name('fl') #駄目
username.click()

エラー→InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument


●driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="F_ga7510"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/fieldset/div/div"]').click() #駄目

エラー→Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[@id="F_ga7510"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/fieldset/div/div"] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[@id="F_ga7510"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/fieldset/div/div"]' is not a valid XPath expression.


●driver.find_element_by_id('fl').click() #駄目

エラー→InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument


●driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="fl"]').click() #駄目

エラー→InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument


●driver.find_element_by_name('fl').click() #駄目

エラー→InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument


●driver.find_element_by_class_name('controls').click() 

エラー→なし。無反応なので、おしいのかも！？
```

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

- Python 3.7.3
- Windows7
- jupyter notebook

Comment: ファイル選択ボタンの場合は `click()` ではなく、`send_keys(file_path)` を使うのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 他のサイトで解決済みのようです。 - https://teratail.com/questions/230536

Comment: ありがとうございます！
解決しました。send_keys(file_path)なんですね。手動でクリックできるものは全部.clickだと思っていました。勉強になりました！